# /etc/issue.net not displaying system information for SSH logins

Tags: ssh, remote-login

I would like to display some system information in `/etc/issue.net`. However, when I `sudo pico /etc/issue.net` and add the following, it just returns plain text when I login

```
user@box:~$ cat /etc/issue.net
This is \n.\O (\s \m \r) \t
```

Here is what it outputs when logging in

```
user@box:~$ ssh localhost
This is \n.\O (\s \m \r) \t

Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-62-generic i686)
```

How do I remedy?

Comment: issue can not be dynamic. If you need dynamic greader, there is `motd`, which can do what you need and is updated by `pam` with every login.

Answer (score 1):

#### Telnet

`/etc/issue.net` is (was) used as an “identification file for telnet sessions”. From the `telnetd` manual page:

> If the file `/etc/issue.net` is present, `telnetd` will display its contents before the login prompt of a telnet session.

The contents of this file are described by the `issue.net(5)` manual page:

> The file `/etc/issue.net` is a text file which contains a message or system identification to be printed before the login prompt of a telnet session. It may contain various `%-char` (or, alternatively, `\-char`) sequences.

Note: its escape sequences are similar to – but not the same as – those supported by `issue.net`, e.g., `\d` and `\t` do the same thing: both print the time *and* date.

#### SSH

The OpenSSH server does **not** display the contents of `issue` or `issue.net`. However, it can be configured to send a pre-login banner (before the password prompt), similar to the Telnet server. The OpenSSH server `Banner` configuration option is described in the `sshd_config(5)` manual page as:

> The contents of the specified file are sent to the remote user before authentication is allowed.

I’m guessing you included the following line in your SSH server configuration:

```
Banner /etc/issue.net
```

However, `sshd` does not interpret any of the `issue.net` escape sequences and the SSH banner file should contain only “static” text (i.e., no special escape sequences).

#### Alternative solution

You can provide dynamic system information to users *after* they’ve logged in by using the `update-motd` package which modifies the *message of the day*.  I haven’t done this myself but the following resources should help you:

- [UpdateMotd - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UpdateMotd#Design)
- [Ubuntu Manpage: pam_motd - Display the motd file](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/pam_motd.8.html)
- [Ubuntu Manpage: update-motd - dynamic MOTD generation](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/update-motd.5.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the getty-type program employed on the system:

```
man issue
```

> The  file /etc/issue is a text file which contains a message or system
>   identification to be printed before the login prompt.  **It may contain
>   various @char and \char sequences, if supported by the getty-type
>   program employed on the system.**

```
man agetty
```

> ISSUE ESCAPES
>          The issue-file (/etc/issue, or the file set with the -f option) may contain certain escape codes to display the system name,  date, 
>   time  etcetera.   All
>          escape codes consist of a backslash () immediately followed by one of the characters listed below.

...

> `n`      Insert the nodename of the machine, also known as the hostname.
>   Same as `uname -n`.
>   `O`      Insert the DNS domainname of the machine.
>   `s`      Insert the system name (the name of the operating system).  Same as `uname -s`.  See also the \S escape code.
>   `m`      Insert the architecture identifier of the machine.  Same as `uname -m`.
>   `r`      Insert the release number of the OS.  Same as `uname -r`.
>   `t`      Insert the current time.

Comment: What you've said is true for local logins but does not apply to this question about SSH logins.